# Linking CMake interface libraries with object libraries

Tags: cmake

I am trying to use interface libraries to define preprocessor macros. These interface libraries will then be linked to other libraries to propagate these macros. This approach has worked with shared libraries I am creating but does not work with CMake object libraries.

I understand that you cannot directly link an interface library to an object library but you can indirectly link the `TARGET_OBJECTS` to the interface library.

[Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries):

> Although object libraries may not be named directly in calls to the `target_link_libraries()` command, they can be “linked” indirectly by using an Interface Library whose `INTERFACE_SOURCES` target property is set to name `$<TARGET_OBJECTS:objlib>`.

I have tried to do this but the object files are still not compiled with the appropriate definitions. Here is the minimal working example:

```cpp
// a.cpp    
int a() {
  return
#ifdef MY_DEF
  5;
#endif
    }
```

CMakeLists:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.1)
project(my_question)

add_library(object_lib OBJECT a.cpp)

add_library(interface_lib INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(interface_lib INTERFACE MY_DEF)

# This does not set the MY_DEF flag
target_sources(interface_lib INTERFACE $<TARGET_OBJECTS:object_lib>)

add_library(main_lib SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:object_lib>)
target_link_libraries(main_lib)
```

Output:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/object_lib.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/object_lib.dir/build
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/object_lib.dir/a.cpp.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++     -o CMakeFiles/object_lib.dir/a.cpp.o -c /Users/umar/devel/so_question/a.cpp
/Users/umar/devel/so_question/a.cpp:7:5: error: expected expression
    }
    ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/object_lib.dir/a.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/object_lib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Based on the documentation this should be possible in CMake. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this is an issue in CMake. I have been able to reproduce this in CMake version 3.6 and 3.8 on Debian and OSX.

Edit:

I have been able to get around this using @utopia's approach but I was curious why the approach I used in my example did not work. I did not know if I was doing this incorrectly or if this was a problem with the tool. Perhaps StackOverflow is not the correct platform for this type of question and I should file a bug report against the project.

Edit2:

As of the most current version of CMake(3.8) this not possible in CMake([see discussion](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16929)). This is something that may be supported in 3.9 via [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/712) merge request. For older versions utopia's answer is the way to go.

Comment: `target_link_libraries(main_lib)` should be `target_link_libraries(main_lib interface_lib)`.

Comment: I think that would only be necessary if I wanted to apply the definitions to the sources of the `main_lib` target. Because the `object_lib` source files are compiled separately the definitions are not applied to it. Nevertheless, I tried `tll(main_lib interface_lib)` but it didn't apply the definitions to the object_lib sources.

Comment: In any case, `target_link_libraries` with the single argument is *useless*. Hm, according to the error log you are compiling *object file* in `object_lib`. If you want this file to have specific definitions, you need to link the `object_lib` target, not the `main_lib` one: `target_link_libraries(object_lib interface_lib)`. Think about *OBJECT* library as set of **precompiled** object files: it is too late for `main_lib` to assign *compile* options for these files.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes. That is why I am not including it in the `target_link_libraries` call. I wanted to apply the definitions to the object files and (at least according to the docs I linked) this should be possible by adding the `object_lib`'s `TARGET_OBJECTS` to the interface libs as I have done in the `target_sources` command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just copy the compile definitions from the interface library directly via properties. The information is there, just no direct support for it via the usual commands:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(my_question)

add_library(interface_lib INTERFACE)
target_compile_definitions(interface_lib INTERFACE MY_DEF)

add_library(object_lib OBJECT a.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(object_lib PUBLIC
  $<TARGET_PROPERTY:interface_lib,INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>)

add_library(main_lib b.cpp)
target_sources(main_lib PRIVATE
  $<TARGET_OBJECTS:object_lib>)
```

Note `target_sources()` was first introduced in version 3.1 not 3.0.1 it seems. It may be a good idea to update your `cmake_minimum_required` version.

Comment: I am aware of this approach and I have been able to do this in my project but it seems like the interface library should be applied to the object library based on the documentation I linked in the question.

Comment: @Umar Arshad are you giving a bug report to stackoverflow.com instead of the CMake project or did you want an answer to solve your question? For someone who obviously took pains to create a minimum viable program for their question and word it well enough to be answered, your objection to a response now is ... strange, especially since you never mentioned this approach in your question at all.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I was not trying to disparage your efforts. I was curious if I was doing this incorrectly or if it is a problem with CMake. I have only started using CMake in this way recently and I thought this was a symptom of my incompetence rather than the tool. I will update the question so this doesn't happen again

Answer (score 9):

Starting from cmake 3.13, object libraries can "link" to other libraries to inherit their usage requirements ([doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries#linking-object-libraries)).

So the example CMakeLists.txt from the question should get the correct definition at compile time.

Don't forget to set cmake_required(VERSION 3.13) if you use this!

Comment: Works like a charm! I've updated from 3.8.2 to 3.15.1 and added `target_compile_options` to a object library target. Now all include directories from the interface library are found.